# Extract a variable length ID from a HTML tag

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

Say I have a HTML tag like:

```
<a href="/works/26339158/chapters/64374943">2</a>
```

But I only want to extract the '26339158'. How can I do this using Python so I can store it in a list?

The HTML tag could be something else like:

```
<a href="/works/26339158?view_full_work=true#comments">58</a>
<a href="/works/26339158">Loud Like Love</a>
```

Comment: Which kind of control do you have over the `a` tag ? Will it ever start with `<a href="/works/` ? Or could it be some arguments before the `href` ?

Comment: It always starts with <a href="/works/ but after that it can change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code uses XML parsing to in order to find the href.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

html = '<a href="/works/26339158/chapters/64374943">2</a>'
root = ET.fromstring(html)
value = root.attrib['href'].split('/')[2]
print(value)
```

output

```
26339158
```

Comment: Can you split for more than one character (without calling split multiples times for each possible separating character) ? Indeed, you can have `26339158?`, thus you're splitting won't work (forgive me if I misunderstood your code)

Comment: Can I split it for '?' and '#' too?

Comment: Please explain what you are looking for